# Automatic opening of hyperlinks within received emails

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a question, I hope someone can help me.

I have to develop an application or a tool bar to do the following:
Whenever I receive a email from anyone, it should open any and all hyperlinks within the email in new browser tabs automatically, without any clicking required.

Is there any way I can do this? Anyone have an idea or some sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check firefox plugins "[Snap Links 0.0.4](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4336)"

*"Snap Links allows users to easily open multiple links in new tabs by drawing a box around them. Links can also be opened in new windows, new tabs on a new window, copied to clipboard, bookmarked or downloaded."*

Answer (score 0):

From a security point of view, this is not a very good idea, because someone can send you email full of links to infected websites utilizing browser exploits.